# Obtaining the length of Coresponding Colors in each row of Image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I've worked on this for some time now with no luck only coming close a time or 2. I've also checked google with no luck so asking for help.
what I'm attempting is scanning each line of image and progress an index as long as the next color is equal to the current pixel then write out a list that contains (1)The length of each corresponding color per row. (2) the x position, and (3) the y position.
any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the RGB values of each pixel, and compare with the next pixel values scanned. use an if else to obtain the value... something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j< image.cols; j++)
    {   
        int b = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
        int g = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
        int r = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
    }
// add your comparison here. Dun wanna do your work for u.
}
```

You can also convert the image to grayscale for faster processing but there will be an information loss.

Comment: could you explain a little the image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0]; also using unsafe code. row[(height * PixelSize) + 3], // blue
        row[(height * PixelSize) + 2], // green
        row[(height * PixelSize) + 1], // red
        row[height * PixelSize] // transparency

Comment: Also voted you +1 as i see where your going with your example as it iterates it writes to svg file using fill. ive got it fiqured out just writing each pixel but takes to much space. looking for a better way by updating the width of the fill element and the updatint the current position

Comment: Yup, that's another way to get the rgb values, another way is to use pointers too. Hmmm. I am a little confused at your 2nd question. As you just wanna get the length of corresponding colour, my idea goes something like this: if current pixel's r value similar to previous pixel's r value, and current pixel's g value similar to previous g value, and same for b, then length++... It should be pretty clear from there(: Or have I misunderstood your question? Haha.

Comment: Oh wait. This needs OpenCV library. Are you using that for your image processing methods?

Comment: no your absolutely correct i created a structure to hold the information needed then wrote to file and came out just as expected

Comment: check out my solution see what you think

Answer (score 1):

I eventually used a structure to store the data until after the for loops to ensure all data was collected correctly. Here is the code used in case someone else may be looking for the same solution.
First we mill make our structure to hold the data needed.

```
internal struct VectorRectangle
{
    public int X,Y,Size;
    public string HexColor;
}
```

Now we have our structure we can obtain our values from our image(Note: it sets the width prop only as height not yet implemented). If you see a way to obtimize code please feel free to do so and message me that you changed something :).

```
internal static unsafe VectorRectangle[] GetRectangles(Bitmap @this)
{
    const int PixelSize = 4;
    List<VectorRectangle> vectorRectangles = new  List<VectorRectangle>();          
    Point dummyPoint;
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(dummyPoint, @this.Size);
    BitmapData bitmapData = @this.LockBits(rectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    for(int height = 0; height < @this.Height; height++)
    {
        VectorRectangle rect = new VectorRectangle();
        rect.Size = 1;
        for(int width = 0; width < @this.Width; width++)
        {
            byte* row = (byte*)(bitmapData.Scan0 + (height * BitmapData.Stride));                   
            rect.X = width;
            rect.Y = height;
            rect.HexColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(
                        row[(width * PixelSize) + 3], // blue
                        row[(width * PixelSize) + 2], // green
                        row[(width * PixelSize) + 1], // red
                        row[width * PixelSize] // transparency
                ));
            while(width < @this.Width && ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(
                        row[((width + 1) * PixelSize) + 3], // blue
                        row[((width + 1) * PixelSize) + 2], // green
                        row[((width + 1) * PixelSize) + 1], // red
                        row[(width + 1) * PixelSize] // transparency
                )) == rect.HexColor) 
            {
                rect.Size++;
                width++;                    }                                       
            vectorRectangles.Add(rect);
        }               
    }
    @this.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    return vectorRectangles.ToArray();
}
```